# 404 in ASP.Net using httphandler

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I use a httphandler to remap browser Urls to files in my website. This works fine but I am having trouble accessing files I created under a new directory. The url looks like this:

```
http://mobile.mysite.com/monitoring/help/help.aspx
```

Yet the information returned in the 404 error shows it cannot find the file under:

```
D:\Sites\Website\monitoring\help\help.aspx
```

Yet the file is really located under:

```
D:\Sites\Website\mobile\monitoring\help\help.aspx
```

My http handler normally recognizes the "mobile" subdomain. In fact, if I leave off the actual file and just use the directory, my handler does get called. Even if I put a breakpoint in my code, VS will never get called. Why is IIS accessing the help.aspx under a directory that doesn't exist? Why isn't my httphandler being called. As I mentioned, the httphandler does work for virtually every other file. I am able to call aspx file located under other domains.

This is how my handler looks in the web.config file:

```
<add name="FileServerHandler-Files" path="*.*" verb="*" type="FileServerHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
```

Running ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS7

The subdomain "mobile" is actually mapped to the same IP address as the main site. Does this have something to do with it? If it does, it doesn't explain why the handler can access folders under the mobile domain but not aspx files.

Answer (score 0):

While I had an entry in the web.config for the handler to handle directories, I tried moving it up in the list. This worked. Why it stopped working is a mystery as the web.config hasn't changed for a very long time. This is what the entries now look like:

```
    <add name="FileServerHandler-Dir" path="*" verb="*" type="FileServerHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
    <add name="FileServerHandler-Files" path="*.*" verb="*" type="FileServerHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
```